# Rider TFS integration

Tags: tfs, rider

I'm attempting to setup an old project on a new computer using Rider with TFS. I'm already using TFS with the same repository on an old computer with Rider, however, I've noticed that on my new computer, TFS is no longer an option for version control. I have the plugin, I can go to version control under settings and view settings for TFS, but when I attempt to enable version control for the project, TFS is not an option. Similarly, I can't checkout from TFS.

Also, the settings screen for TFS is very different on my new computer's install, giving me only the options to delete and update configurations, but no way to add one (so I can't actually do anything). Any ideas about what's gone wrong here?

Comment: Which version control are you using GIT or TFVC? What's detail environment are you using? Could you share more details such as rider/TFS version?  Besides suggest you add some related screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have tested installing `riderRS-171.4456.199.exe` (Windows), the TFS Integration plugin has been bundled with Rider and enabled VCS-TFVC successfully. Seems you are using TFVC version control(check out), please follow below requirements:

> You must have the [TF command line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) installed to be able to
>   use TFVC features. The minimum version supported by the plugin is
>   14.0.3. To install the tool, download the latest "TEE-CLC-14.*.*.zip" file and extract it to a known location. After extracting the files,
>   you must accept the license agreement. To do so, open a Command
>   Prompt/Terminal window, navigate to the extracted directory, and run
>   `tf eula`. After reading the EULA, enter y `enter code here`to accept
>   it. **NOTE:** If you forget to do this, the plugin may fail to load
>   with a RuntimeException.

For the tool to be detected by the plugin, you must set the location of the executable in the Settings/Preferences menu by following these instructions:

1. Go to RD Settings  Version Control -TFVC
2. In the **Path to tf executable** text field, navigate to the location of
       the tf executable.
3. Click **Test** to test that the executable has been found and is working
   as expected.
4. Click **Apply** then **OK** to save and exit.

More details please refer this [tutorial](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-support).

---

Also try to setup a new created project or select another project when you are  using Rider with TFS. To narrow down if the issue is related to that special project.

Comment: I haven't tried installing the command line tool yet, I'll try that. I don't remember doing that on my previous laptop, and the only options I have when enabling VCS on the old laptop was Git, Mercurial, or TFS, whereas the new one has many more (including TFVC). The tutorial referenced also has a bunch of videos in it talking about TFS Git (which is not what I was using), but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The tutorial page does not exist anymore :(